# When is it okay to alias a JavaScript namespace, type, or method?

Tags: javascript, alias

Our team is referencing [Google's JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Naming#Naming).

One section states, "Avoid accessing properties of an aliased type, unless it is an enum" but doesn't elaborate on why.

Aliasing a *method* changes the context of "this" according to the sample code we've ran based on [this article](http://brandon.northcutt.net/article/Javascript+Function+Alias+and+Context+Awareness/20140404.html).

However, I can't find a clear example of why you should not access properties of an aliased type? Does anyone have an example of why this would be bad?

Comment: it would be helpful if you said _which_ section - a page search doesn't find text from unexpanded sections.

Comment: Found it - http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Naming#Naming

Comment: As it states "*Namespaces should only be aliased using `goog.scope`.*", I would assume this destroys some pattern recognisition in the closure compiler.

Comment: A better question is why are you following the Google JS Style Guide? It's notoriously terrible and Google-specific.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: actually most of the stuff that actually relates to JS i agree with. since enums and types in general are something google made up, they get to set the rules. nobody uses "aliased types", and it's just fine to use short paths to invoke. imagine using document.documentElement.children[0].appendChild instead of body.appendChild each time...

Comment: @dandavis: Google made up namespaces as well (after all, jQuery follows different standards), which makes the question stylistic in nature and not based on something like the ECMA standard.

Comment: in the context of a style guide and teams, it seems to me that having the full "breadcrumb" to global would help developers jump around code without having to decipher local variables. i can also see how that would protect against accidentally tacking a property on to the entire caboose that's only needed for a single function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a JavaScript `namespace`, `method`, or `type`. Okay, maybe there are things like methods (let's just call them functions), but namespaces and types can mean different things to different people. To Google, they mean whatever you find in their style guide.

JavaScript is a prototypal language devoid of some of the features found in C++ or Java (polymorphism, inheritance, namespaces, typing, Eve objects, etc.). The Google style guide (it's not the only one of its kind, see Douglas Crockford) presents a number of stylistic constraints. These constraints are often have no syntactic value, but are merely stylistic in nature (as my comment mentions).

For example, all namespaces need to be aliased via `goog.scope`. This may be used for closure compiler compatibility, readability, debugging, or just because it looks pretty. To address your question, it wouldn't be bad per se to access an aliased type's properties and even the issue you bring up (losing the `this` context) can be solved with something like `.apply(...)` or `.bind(...)`.

Furthermore (and this is just me ranting), the term **aliased type** has a pretty concrete meaning in other languages; I think it's stupid to use it in the context of JS -- which is has an incredibility vague idea of types to begin with.